# Weblogic 12c Unable to access the selected application. failed to load java type corresponding to e=web-fragment

Tags: java, sapui5, weblogic12c

I build a war file using maven and it contains SAPUI5 jar files when I try to load it in weblogic I get this error

Unable to access the selected application.
failed to load java type corresponding to e=web-fragment

this fragment comes from an SAPUI5 jar com.sap.ui5.utils-1.44.24.jar
it works great in Tomcat but fails every time in weblogic 12c.

Any clue would be helpful